# Defaulting the record type in few cases

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities, simple-salesforce, sfdc

I have created 2 record types for Account object in Salesforce.
I have assigned different page layouts for both of them.
Name of the record types are 'Parent account' and 'Child Account'.
When I click on new button of account which used for creation of a new record, I want to default the record type to parent account and the layout for that should be opened.

The only use of 'Child Account' record type here is for lead conversion.
During the lead conversion, the account that gets created will be of record type 'Child Account'.

I tried by giving profile permissions, but that didn't help and I was able to see both the options for selection every time.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Enhanced Profile User Interface,

```
1.Head over to the desired Profile.

2.Go to the ‘Record Type Settings’ section.

3.Click [Edit] and select the desired default value. Hope this helps!
```